# I have an error; no default constructor in h file, how do I set valid constructors

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I have the following lines in a API I'm trying to work with:

```
    public value struct DeviceInfo
{
    Byte    DeviceCompatibility;
    Size    imageSize;

    static initonly DeviceInfo Empty = { (Size::Empty, 0 ) };
};
```

When I compile(Build) the project I get the error

`System::Drawing::Size` No appropriate default constructor available

The code is inside a h file; Can someone help with what I should do; I'm working in VS 2015.

Comment: I think we need more information here to be able to help you. Yoy could start with adding which API you are using and perhaps how you call this code and alot more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this C++/CLI value class definition

```
public value struct DeviceInfo
{
    Byte    DeviceCompatibility;
    Size    imageSize;

    static initonly DeviceInfo Empty = { (Size::Empty, 0 ) };
};
```

there is data member `imageSize` of type `Size`. And the compiler error message says that there is no default constructor for this class.

Either you have to initialize this data member explicitly in the class definition or to write the class constructor which will initialize this data member.

According to the `Size` class description it has the following constructors

```
Size(Int32, Int32)
Size(Point)
```

As you can see each constructor requires to specify an argument or arguments.

I think you could use the same static data member `Size::Empty` to initialize the data member `imageSize`

Try for example

```
    Size    imageSize = Size::Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add more information like what language that is.

I guess this is c++/cli and the problem you're facing might be a typical c++ issue, where "Size" is a type only introduced by a simple "struct Size;" without a proper definition.

It would be an error in the header you quoted, failing to include the header that provides the definition of "Size", which would look like "struct Size{ ... }"

You might be able to solve the problem on your end by including that other header file just one line above your inclusion of the quoted header file.

Comment: "You may want to add more information like what language that is."?

Comment: Yes, there is a tag c++/cli, but I don't think it was there.

Comment: Also I think my answer is wrong. Vlad has it right.